# Xamarin.Android code compilation

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/introduction-to-mobile-development):

> On Android, Xamarin’s compiler compiles down to Intermediate Language (IL), which is then Just-in-Time (JIT) compiled to native assembly when the application launches.

So if I'm developing for Android using `Xamarin.Android` and C# language, my code that is in C# gets compiled into IL, which is then at run time compiled into some native assembly. What is meant by this native assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...compiled to native assembly...`

The Mono runtime on Android JITs the IL to the platform's processor-based native code, that could be 32 or 64-bit ARM/Thumb instructions and on Intel that would be x86_32 and x86_64 instructions.